# Where is the "Open with" option to open a jump list item with a different application?

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

Between four separate Windows 7 machines, I've noticed that the option to right-click a jump list item and select "Open with" to open a file with a different application is nowhere to be seen.  Being able to open a text file in regular Notepad when my default text editor is Notepad2 can be helpful at times.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked 3 of our Windows 7 machines and this option still exists. It does look like many others have run into the same problem as you, one resolution being to edit the registry. I can't comment on this working or not from personal experience, but there are several users who claim this helped. If you're going to try this, **backup your registry.**

```
1. Click Start, All Programs, Accesories, Notepad.
2. Copy and paste this text:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]
@="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"

3. Click File, Save As, name the file "OpenWith.reg" (WITH THE QUOTATION MARKS) and click OK.
4. Now double-click OpenWith.reg, click Continue, Yes, OK, and see if the problem is solved.
```

It's possible that the 4 Windows machines you've looked at are off of the same image.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/right-click-open-with-command-missing-help-please/a9c3f139-075c-4285-b87d-25e899fb8b27